# trying to make a div resize height automatically depending on how much content there is in a containing div

Tags: jquery, drupal, html, height, resize

I'm trying to make a div (.bottom) resize automatically when the contents of another div (.column.c) changes between being more or less.

I'm guessing i need to use jquery but i haven't got a clue where to start. It would be nice if it resized smoothly!

I'm using drupal and a views slideshow of a content type that i've created.

cheers guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".bottom").height($(".column.c").height());
    });
</script>
```

You would need to put this code under whatever event changes the size of the `.column.c` div.

Comment: sorry i dont understand jquery at all.

Comment: nothing is changing the size of the .column.c div it just has either more or less text in it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply it still doesn't seem to be working. the site address is 2012.qdos.co if that helps.